# matplotlib bar graph from a pandas series of value counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot a graph in python which would show me the occurrence of items over time.
So I want to find out how many items that match two categories appear in each year and plot a graph based on these.

This is my data in excel:

[image]

What I want to end up with is a list of movies which are both fantasy and action and how many times they appear in every year.
This is the end result which I have gotten to (which is correct)

[image]

i.e. there are 2 movies in 2004 which are both fantasy and action and there is one movie in 2005 which is both fantasy and action etc.

Here are the steps which I have taken to get to the result:

```
#import data:
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

#put all fantasy movies in a list:
fantasy_movies = data[['Name', 'Genre']][(data['Genre'] == 'Fantasy')]
fantasy_movies.rename(columns={'Genre' : 'Fantasy'}, inplace = True)

#put all action movies in a list:
action_movies = data[['Name', 'Genre']][(data['Genre'] == 'Action')]
action_movies.rename(columns={'Genre' : 'Action'}, inplace = True)

#merge the two datasets:
action_fantasy = pd.merge(fantasy_movies, action_movies)

#obtain a list of unique movie names:
unique = action_fantasy.Name.unique()

#make dates the column and unique names the rows
filter_data = data[(data.Name.isin(unique))] 
table = filter_data.pivot_table(filter_data, index = ['Name'],columns=['year'])

#replace all NaNs with zero
table1 = table.fillna(0)

#Count items in years
table1.gt(0).astype(int).sum(axis=0)
```

Now, from here I would like to do some kind of graph (I'm thinking of a bar graph) using Matplotlib that would have years on the bottom and going up by the amount as per the table1 result.
I am struggling to create one, even though it should technically be as easy as putting data on the x column and data on the y column.

Like the code from W3 Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_bars.asp

```
x = np.array(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
y = np.array([3, 8, 1, 10])

plt.bar(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I wonder if my data is in the wrong format? What would be my x-axis and y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if my data is in the wrong format?

Not "wrong" per se, but it has a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) which is a bit of a hassle and unnecessary here. I suggest getting rid of the MultiIndex with [`Series.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html) before plotting via pandas/matplotlib/seaborn.

---

### pandas bar plot

After dropping the MultiIndex, use [`Series.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html) which plots the values as *y* against the index as *x*:

```
counts = table1.gt(0).astype(int).sum(axis=0).droplevel(0)
# year
# 2004    2
# 2005    1
# 2011    1
# 2016    1
# 2018    2
# dtype: int64

counts.plot.bar(ylabel='total')
```

[image]

---

### matplotlib bar plot

If you really want to use [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html), I suggest resetting the Series into a DataFrame and then plotting the total against the range index:

```
counts = table1.gt(0).astype(int).sum(axis=0).droplevel(0).reset_index(name='total')
#    year  total
# 0  2004      2
# 1  2005      1
# 2  2011      1
# 3  2016      1
# 4  2018      2

plt.bar(counts.index, counts.total)
plt.xticks(ticks=counts.index, labels=counts.year)
plt.xlabel('year')
plt.ylabel('total')
```

[image]

---

### seaborn bar plot

Alternatively pass the DataFrame into [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=counts, x='year', y='total')
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you so much for the tip! It works perfect :)